# Multiply items in list

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to write a function (for academic reasons) that multiply every number in this list : `list = [6 , [1, 2, 3]]`
I have tried this solution:

```
def grow(arr):
    for num in arr:
        x = num
        x * num
        for value in num:
            y = value * num
        return y * x
```

But I keep getting: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable someone help me understand please.
The expected output should be: 36.
The function should do this: 6 * 1 * 2 * 3

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the comment i have **fixed it**

Comment: Check my answer. You can pass any type of list it will compute the value. Even will work for this: `li = [[[4] ,3, [1, 2, 3]]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or something similar with one of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66345510/6446053) which first flattned the nested list using the `flatten` and using `numpy prod` to calculate the cross multiplication.

```
import numpy  as np
def flatten(li):
    try:
        for item in li:
            yield from flatten(item)
    except TypeError:
        yield li

li = [6,[1, 2, 3]]
list1 = [fi for fi in flatten(li)]

result1 = np.prod(list1)
```

Initially, the OP accept the suggestion per the code below

Extract the nested list

```
num, val_list = [6 , [1, 2, 3]]
```

multiply and add all the value in the list

```
expected_output=sum([value * num for value in val_list])
```

As a function:

```
def grow(arr):
 num, val_list = arr
 return sum([value * num for value in val_list])


my_arr= [6 , [1, 2, 3]]
data=grow(my_arr)
```

Comment: Your answer looks like the right one but I am having trouble in turning into a function can you help me?

Comment: and you also made a wrong sum call but your solution is the cleanest

Comment: what do you mean by wrong sum call?

Comment: Have you tested your code?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but it did not work. I got a ValueError

Comment: can you try again. Also, in your question please edit the list from `[[6 , [1, 2, 3]]` to `[6 , [1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: I get the exact output in my compiler. Also, the first two lines indicate that the you get what is originally requested

Comment: can you  try print(data)

Comment: In the question it is mentioned, what is to be done is `6*1*2*3`  but I think this code is doing something like `(6*1)+(6*2)+(6*3)`. Though the answers match in this very case, other cases will generate different results.

Comment: `[4 , [0, 2, 3]]` should give 0 but it is giving `20` as  @YashvanderBamel has pointed out. The logic is totally wrong Plus  `num, val_list = ....` Solution should be general. not specific to a single case.

Comment: Please note that, the OP has made the modification after the I suggested this approach. Prior that, I drafted the code based on the text `expected output should be: 36`.

Comment: Please note that, the OP has made the modification after the  suggestion I made. Prior to that, I drafted the code based on the text `expected output should be: 36`

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
def flatten(li):
    try:
        for item in li:
            yield from flatten(item)
    except TypeError:
        yield li

li = [6,[1, 2, 3]]
l = [fi for fi in flatten(li)]
reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, l)
```

---

```
36
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're pretty sure that `arr` will always contain just two entries like `[6, [1, 2, 3]]` the above solutions are good to go. But what if someone supplied something like this - `[1, [2, 3, 4], 5, 6, [2, 4, 5]]`. Provided all the values are integers you can do the following:

```
def grow(arr):
    temp = list()
    for i in arr:
        if type(i) == int:
            temp.append(i)
        else:
            temp.extend(i)

    return temp
```

Now that all the elements have been taken into the new list `temp`, you can `import math` and do `math.prod(temp)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def grow(arr):
    for num in arr:
        x = num
        x * num
        for value in num:
            y = value * num
        return y * x
```

When your outer `for` loop iterates, it finds two elements in the list: `6` and `[1, 2, 3]`.  therefore, the first time through that loop, `num` is `6`.

Therefore, your inner `for` resolves to

```
        for value in 6:
```

Which is not possible.  Instead, you need to take the two list elements in sequence, not as a nested loop.

```
num, val_list = arr
for value in val_list:
    y = value * num
```

That fixes your immediate problem.  I'll leave the other errors up to you.  You still have to store all three products; in the loop above, you overwrite the first two with the last one.